# Integrating Webpack in legacy AngularJS Website (Java/Spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring, reactjs, webpack, redux

I've started curating an old web project based on tons of java code (old spring version) and a singular monolithic frontend module a.k.a. "The web-module" and I'm trying to upgrade the build steps and migrate old angularJS code bit by bit.

The idea was to implement Redux as a single point of truth between old and new code and Webpack for bundling new js files (vanillaJS/React) and other assets and integrating them in the old .jsp files that are littered with lots and lots of good old  tags.

The old code is a mix of Javascript, jQuery and AngularJS, events are handled by jquery, I'm getting lots of funny side effects of conflicting / competing angularJS $scopes for every module I touched so far.

How does a sane individual integrate dist/ files generated by webpack into old .jsp files without messing everything up and/or losing her/his sanity? I feel kinda overwhelmed by all the things that might go wrong and I'm searching everywhere for success stories of people trying stuff like this. All I could find so far were migration guides but that's not an option with about 80-100 legacy angularJS files that would have to be rewritten for webpack so I need a solution that works side by side until I've managed to rewrite all the old angularJS Modules, one update at a time.

Comment: I saw a talk that faced exactly this kind of issue, migrating away from an old AngulaJS installation one step at time.
https://vimeo.com/channels/jsday/274520915

The video itself is short due to timing limit of the conference, you should look for  the extended version, where the Angular section is more detailed.

Comment: yeah, good old strangular. ^^
I've seen something like that but in a different way. Gonna check that video tomorrow. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah, they have done what I'm about to do but I guess I'm looking for more of a guide/tutorial with real examples, code etc. Still a good talk though.